Does First order Logic require the subsistence/existence of a universal set, i.e. a set of all things?
In Irving M. Copi's 'Symbolic Logic' he postulates an unlimited set of individual constants.  Each constant denotes an individual, so it seems he accounted for a set of all things U. First order logic just seems more intuitive with the axiom (or theorem)
∀x[x ∈ U]
Is there a way to prove this statement is required by FOL,thus going against ZFC?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
